# Logic error in string building

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a program I'm writing that's supposed to encrypt and decrypt a predetermined set of strings. The main class was provided and I had to write the dependencies, but my objects are not getting called correctly, creating a large cascade of compile-time errors. Both of the dependencies compile fine on their own, so I have to have made a mistake in the interface between classes. It's quite a bit of code so here is a pastebin link:

http://pastebin.com/i2V51TJm

EDIT: Now I'm getting major logic errors. I know it's in the encryptor, and possibly the decryptor as well, but I have used the decryptor idependently previously and all I did here was change X from a fixed value to the difficulty.

EDIT 2: Have now fixed randChar, now I just need to figure out whats wrong in my en/decrypt loops.

here is my new error/output:

```
==============================
Simulating difficulty level 0:
Encrypting String: kitty ...
Encrypted as: xvrdsoyttik
Decrypting String: xvrdsoyttik ...
Decrypted as: kkkkkkkkkkkk
Fail!
==============================
Simulating difficulty level 1:
Encrypting String: test string ...
Encrypted as: gqpyqfdqqwvcqnirts tset
Decrypting String: gqpyqfdqqwvcqnirts tset ...
Decrypted as: test strinqcvwqqdfqypqg
Fail!
==============================
Simulating difficulty level 2:
Encrypting String: Agent: James Bond ...
Encrypted as: dnjomBe bsveimqaiJa :tnegA
Decrypting String: dnjomBe bsveimqaiJa :tnegA ...
Decrypted as: Aet James Bon
Fail!
==============================
```

Encryptor:

```
/** 
    encryptString encrypts the string, as well as stores the original for later use
    @param str The string to be encrypted
    @return encrypted The encrypted string
    */
    public String encryptString(String str)
    {
        int length = str.length();
        origStr = str;
        int x = diff;
        StringBuilder codeRev = new StringBuilder(str).reverse();

         for (int pos = 0; pos <= length; pos++)
         {
            if (x <= length + diff) //removed 
            {
                codeRev.insert(x, randomLetter());
            }               
            x = x + diff + 1;
         }
         encryptedStr = codeRev.toString();
         return(codeRev).toString();

    }
```

Decryptor:

```
/**
decryptString decrypts the code based on using the difficulty as the increment.
@param code The encrypted string
@return decrypted The decrypted string
*/
    public String decryptString(String code)
    {
        int length = code.length();
        int x = 0; //to 1
        encryptedStr = code;

        String codeRev = new StringBuilder(code).reverse().toString();

        StringBuilder decrypted = new StringBuilder();

         for (int pos = 0; pos <= length; pos++)
         {
            if (x < length) //removed <=
            {
                decrypted.append(codeRev.charAt(x));
            }               
            x = x + diff;
         }
         decryptedStr = decrypted.toString();
         return(decrypted).toString();
    }
```

Random Character maker:

```
/**
    Generates a random letter
    @return letter The random letter
    */
    public char randomLetter()
    {
        Random ranChar = new Random();
        char cr = (char)(ranChar.nextInt(26)+ 'a');
        return cr;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that anyone is going to read all 230 lines of code. Extract the problem and post only the relevant code. And how do you think that anyone can find your problem if you don't actually tell us what those compiler errors say?

Comment: Fixed compile time errors, now just two logic errors as far as I can figure. Something has to be wrong with the increments on my loops, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty straight forward- there's no `getDecryptedStr()` method in `Decryptor`, and no `getEncryptedStr()` method in `Encryptor`

Generally speaking - if you got to these errors, it looks like you are not working with any IDE. You should start working with one, like [idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) or [eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/). You will see such compilation errors right away

Comment: Thanks, I caught that about two minutes ago! I'm working in textpad++ with some addons, I'll look into eclipse in the future, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately some logic errors have slipped through, namely in the encrypt/decrypt process, would you be willing to help with that too?

Comment: @brodieR - your problem is with `x <= length` - remember that `String.charAt(x)` works from 0 to length-1, not from 1 to length. so in case x=length- you're out of bounds

Comment: There are unkown character popping up, that has to be the randChar's fault, but your fix for the encrypt decrypt does not appear to have made a noticeable difference

Comment: I'm not talking about randChar, I'm talking about `decryptString(String code)` - if x=length,  you'll get the index out of bounds, since charAt() works from 0 to length-1. it should be `x<length`, not `<=`

Comment: I see what you're saying, and I recompiled with that change and I still get exceptions thrown. Let me explain better what this is intended to do: based on the difficulty, insert x amount of random letters between the "real" letters, then reverse the string and remove them. diff=0 encryption works fine, but I think my decryption loop is one of the problems as well.